# Docker YAML error: service must be a mapping, not a NoneType

Tags: docker-compose, yaml

I tried to adjust the indentation for my YAML file but when I run `docker-compose`, I'm still seeing the "service must be a mapping, not a NoneType." error.

[image]

Pasted YAML file here:

```
version: "3.1" services:   postgres-source:
    image: postgres:12.6
    ports:
      - "5439:5432"
    environment: - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres   postgres-target:
    image: postgres:12.6
    ports:
    - "5440:5432"
    environment: - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres command: [ "postgres", "-c", "wal_level=logical" ]
```

Comment: When you published this question did the indentation changed ? This is not a yaml valid syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The indentation of your YAML file doesn't look correct. Please try this format instead:

```
version: "3.1"
services:
  postgres-source:
    image: postgres:12.6
    ports:
      - "5439:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres   
  postgres-target:
    image: postgres:12.6
    ports:
      - "5440:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    command: [ "postgres", "-c", "wal_level=logical" ]
```

Comment: Thank you! I was having trouble figuring out the right indentation. This worked!!

Comment: @cobtri https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/yaml/